# Необходимо переделать код из matlab в python

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7, matlab

Есть код *matlab*, необходимо переделать его под *python2.7* с использованием *matlab.engine*

```
img = imread('light.jpg');
r = img(:,:,1);
rt = imread('red_template.png');
rt = rt(:,:,1);
c=normxcorr2(rt, r);
maxValue = max(max(c));
[y x] = find(c == max(c(:)));
disp(maxValue);
imshow(c);
```

Пробовал сам, получилось вот так, но не работает

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
img = eng.imread('light.jpg')
r = img[::1]
rt = eng.imread('red_template.png')
rt = rt[: :1]
c=eng.normxcorr2(rt, r)
maxValue = eng.max(eng.max(c))
[y,x] = eng.find(c == max(c(:)));
print(maxValue);
eng.imshow(c);
```

Конкретно не получается правильно преобразовать матрицу изображений

Comment: Добавьте более расширенный комментарий по тому, что конкретно не работает. Ошибки, исключения, результат не соответствует ожиданиям?

Comment: а чего print так написан?В 2.7 пишется print maxValue и в python нету точек с запятой после операций.